# django - getting related subclassed objects

Tags: python, django

Building a custom form application I got the following `models.py`

```
#models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_title = models.TextField(...)


class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_title = models.TextField(...)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BoolAnswer(Answer):
    result = models.BooleanField(...)
    if_answer = models.TextField(...)
    else_answer = models.TextField(...)

class NumberAnswer(Answer):
    answer = models.DecimalField(...)

class MultipleChoiceAnswer(...):
    ....
```

Now I am trying to get all answers belonging to one question using:

```
question.answer_set.all()
```

which does not exist. There are only

```
question.boolanswer_set
question.numberanswer_set
....
```

etc.

Is there an elegant way to get all answers?

Comment: `answer_set` does not exist unless you have a `related_name` attribute set. Can you edit the question with the traceback ?

Comment: [This is the `InheritenceModelManager`](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) mentioned in one of the answers in the duplicate link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @TimmyO'Mahony : One needs

https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

the following code works: (thx @kathikr):

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_title = models.TextField(...)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answer_set')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = InheritanceManager()
```

Now `question.answer_set.all()` gets all answer subclass objects